# (Python)What do I do to stop receiving this error? [WinError 10013]An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: sockets, python-3.7, python-sockets

I'm trying to make a python socket client/server chat app, but can't seem to work around [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ComLI.png). I've used `netstat -a|findstr 7000` to make sure the port was available, [and it was.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb1wA.png) I don't have any antivirus running besides Windows Security. I also tried it after turning off all firewalls on my computer--have not messed with firewall settings in my router. I'm running both files in Anaconda Powershell Prompt as admin.
Any help is appreciated.

Code for server.py :

```
from socket import AF_INET, socket, SOCK_STREAM
import threading

BUFSIZ = 1024
FORMAT = 'utf-8'             
SERVER = '192.168.1.10'
ADDR = (SERVER, 7000)                                           

server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)
sockets = {server}  
clients = {}        

def accept_incoming_connections(): 
    while True:
        client, client_addr = server.accept()                
        print ("%s:%s has connected." % client_addr)            
        client.send(bytes("Enter your name and press enter."), FORMAT) 
        sockets[client] = client_addr                          
       # client_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,)).start()

def handle_client(client):   
    client_name = client.recv(BUFSIZ).decode(FORMAT)            
    client.send(bytes("Type .exit when you're ready to quit.", FORMAT))
    msg = "%s has entered the chat." % client_name
    broadcast(bytes(msg, FORMAT))                               
    clients[client] = client_name

    while True:                                         
        msg = client.recv(BUFSIZ)                       
        if msg == bytes(".exit", FORMAT):               
            client.send(bytes(".exit", FORMAT))         
            client.close()
            del clients[client]
            broadcast(bytes("%s has left the chat." % client_name, FORMAT))
            break
        else:                                           
            broadcast(msg, client_name)

def broadcast(msg, name=""):                    
    for client in clients:                      
        client.send(bytes(name, FORMAT) + msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server.listen()
    print("Awaiting connection.")
    accept_incoming_connections()
```

Code for client.py :

```
import socket
import threading

BUFSIZ = 1024
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
SERVER = '192.168.1.10'
ADDR = (SERVER, 7000) 

client_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_sock.connect(ADDR)

def receive():
    msg = client_sock.recv(BUFSIZ).decode(FORMAT)
    print(msg)

def send():
    msg = input('Enter msg: ')
    msg.encode(FORMAT)
    client_sock.send(msg)
    if msg == ".exit":
        client_sock.close()

receive_thread = Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()
```

#### EDIT: I fixed it. I set SERVER to 'localhost' and PORT to 9999 for both server and client.

Comment: I guess you're running on same network, ain't you?

Comment: @GameDev Yes, in the same network. I'm going to try connecting to ethernet when I get home.